# Pandas inner merge producing new duplicate rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Best Actress dataframe like the one below.

```
Year    Ceremony    Award       Winner  Name            Film        Ceremony_Date
1927/1928   1   Best Actress    NaN Louise Dresser  A Ship Comes In 1929-05-16
1927/1928   1   Best Actress    1.0 Janet Gaynor    7th Heaven      1929-05-16
1927/1928   1   Best Actress    NaN Gloria Swanson  Sadie Thompson  1929-05-16
1928/1929   2   Best Actress    NaN Ruth Chatterton Madame X        1930-04-03
1928/1929   2   Best Actress    NaN Betty Compson   The Barker      1930-04-03
```

I did an inner join (merge) with the following best actress' date of birth dataframe on the name column, as I want the above dataframe to also have date of birth info.

```
    Name           DOB
0   Janet Gaynor    1906-10-06
1   Louise Dresser  1878-10-17
2   Gloria Swanson  1899-03-27
3   Mary Pickford   1892-04-08
4   Ruth Chatterton 1892-12-24
5   Betty Compson   1897-03-19
```

EDIT --> `ba_dob = pd.merge(ba, df_birthdays, how='inner', on='Name')`

The result was a dataframe with duplicate rows. For example (see below), Meryl Streep gets nominated for a film once and that record (after the join) is mysteriously duplicated an ungodly number of times. I thought the inner join was simply going to associate a date of birth with a name wherever there was a match on the name column between the two dataframes, not recopy whole records. I tried a left join with the best actress table as the left table and got a similar duplication of records. Any insight into to what is happening would be appreciated.

```
Year    Ceremony    Award   Winner  Name    Film       Ceremony_Date    DOB
    1102    1981    54  Best Actress    NaN Meryl Streep    The French Lieutenant's Woman   1982-03-29  1949-06-22
    1103    1981    54  Best Actress    NaN Meryl Streep    The French Lieutenant's Woman   1982-03-29  1949-06-22
    1104    1981    54  Best Actress    NaN Meryl Streep    The French Lieutenant's Woman   1982-03-29  1949-06-22
    1105    1981    54  Best Actress    NaN Meryl Streep    The French Lieutenant's Woman   1982-03-29  1949-06-22
    1106    1981    54  Best Actress    NaN Meryl Streep    The French Lieutenant's Woman   1982-03-29  1949-06-22
    1107    1981    54  Best Actress    NaN Meryl Streep    The French Lieutenant's Woman   1982-03-29  1949-06-22
    1108    1981    54  Best Actress    NaN Meryl Streep    The French Lieutenant's Woman   1982-03-29  1949-06-22
```

**EDIT** Here are the above dataframe heads in dict form (by request):

Best Actress

```
{'Award': {2: 'Best Actress',
  3: 'Best Actress',
  4: 'Best Actress',
  40: 'Best Actress',
  41: 'Best Actress'},
 'Ceremony': {2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 40: 2, 41: 2},
 'Ceremony_Date': {2: Timestamp('1929-05-16 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('1929-05-16 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('1929-05-16 00:00:00'),
  40: Timestamp('1930-04-03 00:00:00'),
  41: Timestamp('1930-04-03 00:00:00')},
 'Film': {2: 'A Ship Comes In',
  3: '7th Heaven',
  4: 'Sadie Thompson',
  40: 'Madame X',
  41: 'The Barker'},
 'Name': {2: 'Louise Dresser',
  3: 'Janet Gaynor',
  4: 'Gloria Swanson',
  40: 'Ruth Chatterton',
  41: 'Betty Compson'},
 'Winner': {2: nan, 3: 1.0, 4: nan, 40: nan, 41: nan},
 'Year': {2: '1927/1928',
  3: '1927/1928',
  4: '1927/1928',
  40: '1928/1929',
  41: '1928/1929'}}
```

Dates of Birth

```
{'DOB': {0: Timestamp('1906-10-06 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('1878-10-17 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('1899-03-27 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('1892-04-08 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('1892-12-24 00:00:00')},
 'Name': {0: 'Janet Gaynor',
  1: 'Louise Dresser',
  2: 'Gloria Swanson',
  3: 'Mary Pickford',
  4: 'Ruth Chatterton'}}
```

Merged (inner Join) Dataframe

```
{'Award': {0: 'Best Actress',
  1: 'Best Actress',
  2: 'Best Actress',
  3: 'Best Actress',
  4: 'Best Actress'},
 'Ceremony': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 10, 4: 10},
 'Ceremony_Date': {0: Timestamp('1929-05-16 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('1929-05-16 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('1929-05-16 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('1938-03-10 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('1938-03-10 00:00:00')},
 'DOB': {0: Timestamp('1878-10-17 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('1906-10-06 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('1906-10-06 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('1906-10-06 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('1906-10-06 00:00:00')},
 'Film': {0: 'A Ship Comes In',
  1: '7th Heaven',
  2: '7th Heaven',
  3: 'A Star Is Born',
  4: 'A Star Is Born'},
 'Name': {0: 'Louise Dresser',
  1: 'Janet Gaynor',
  2: 'Janet Gaynor',
  3: 'Janet Gaynor',
  4: 'Janet Gaynor'},
 'Winner': {0: nan, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.0, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 'Year': {0: '1927/1928',
  1: '1927/1928',
  2: '1927/1928',
  3: '1937',
  4: '1937'}}
```

**EDIT**

Meryl Streep entires from Best Actress dataframe

```
{'Award': {5957: 'Best Actress',
  6061: 'Best Actress',
  6172: 'Best Actress',
  6389: 'Best Actress',
  6606: 'Best Actress',
  6708: 'Best Actress',
  6922: 'Best Actress',
  7483: 'Best Actress',
  7835: 'Best Actress',
  7950: 'Best Actress',
  8748: 'Best Actress',
  8983: 'Best Actress',
  9098: 'Best Actress',
  9347: 'Best Actress',
  9599: 'Best Actress'},
 'Ceremony': {5957: 54,
  6061: 55,
  6172: 56,
  6389: 58,
  6606: 60,
  6708: 61,
  6922: 63,
  7483: 68,
  7835: 71,
  7950: 72,
  8748: 79,
  8983: 81,
  9098: 82,
  9347: 84,
  9599: 86},
 'Ceremony_Date': {5957: Timestamp('1982-03-29 00:00:00'),
  6061: Timestamp('1983-04-11 00:00:00'),
  6172: Timestamp('1984-04-09 00:00:00'),
  6389: Timestamp('1986-03-24 00:00:00'),
  6606: Timestamp('1988-04-11 00:00:00'),
  6708: Timestamp('1989-03-29 00:00:00'),
  6922: Timestamp('1991-03-25 00:00:00'),
  7483: Timestamp('1996-03-25 00:00:00'),
  7835: Timestamp('1999-03-21 00:00:00'),
  7950: Timestamp('2000-03-26 00:00:00'),
  8748: Timestamp('2007-02-25 00:00:00'),
  8983: Timestamp('2009-02-22 00:00:00'),
  9098: Timestamp('2010-03-07 00:00:00'),
  9347: Timestamp('2012-02-26 00:00:00'),
  9599: Timestamp('2014-03-02 00:00:00')},
 'Film': {5957: "The French Lieutenant's Woman",
  6061: "Sophie's Choice",
  6172: 'Silkwood',
  6389: 'Out of Africa',
  6606: 'Ironweed',
  6708: 'A Cry in the Dark',
  6922: 'Postcards from the Edge',
  7483: 'The Bridges of Madison County',
  7835: 'One True Thing',
  7950: 'Music of the Heart',
  8748: 'The Devil Wears Prada',
  8983: 'Doubt',
  9098: 'Julie & Julia',
  9347: 'The Iron Lady',
  9599: 'August: Osage County'},
 'Name': {5957: 'Meryl Streep',
  6061: 'Meryl Streep',
  6172: 'Meryl Streep',
  6389: 'Meryl Streep',
  6606: 'Meryl Streep',
  6708: 'Meryl Streep',
  6922: 'Meryl Streep',
  7483: 'Meryl Streep',
  7835: 'Meryl Streep',
  7950: 'Meryl Streep',
  8748: 'Meryl Streep',
  8983: 'Meryl Streep',
  9098: 'Meryl Streep',
  9347: 'Meryl Streep',
  9599: 'Meryl Streep'},
 'Winner': {5957: nan,
  6061: 1.0,
  6172: nan,
  6389: nan,
  6606: nan,
  6708: nan,
  6922: nan,
  7483: nan,
  7835: nan,
  7950: nan,
  8748: nan,
  8983: nan,
  9098: nan,
  9347: 1.0,
  9599: nan},
 'Year': {5957: '1981',
  6061: '1982',
  6172: '1983',
  6389: '1985',
  6606: '1987',
  6708: '1988',
  6922: '1990',
  7483: '1995',
  7835: '1998',
  7950: '1999',
  8748: '2006',
  8983: '2008',
  9098: '2009',
  9347: '2011',
  9599: '2013'}}
```

Comment: Please include your code.

Comment: Merge command added. There's not much code to this one.

Comment: Can you pass the first dataframe with ba.to_dict() or ba.head().to_dict()?

Comment: @AntonvBR -- I am unfamiliar with those commands or why I would use them here. Fairly new to pandas.

Comment: @Ryan U use them to share your data. The output is a dictionary that is easy to read into pandas.

Comment: You'll get more help if you make it easy to read in your dfs with a pd.read_clipboard().

Comment: @AntonvBR - Added dict views of dataframes per your request. I hope it's what you were asking for.

Comment: @Ryan This makes everyone happy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer what was clearly an abysmally asked question on my part, allow me to pinpoint what the problem was and identify the workaround.

As noted above, the best actress dataframe, `ba`, was fine. In fact, all dataframes were in order. The original question was about how the inner join was being performed and what could possibly be going wrong (i.e., prompting the merge process to create duplicate records).

Meryl Streep will be our guide here, as above. In the data set, she had 16 nominations for Best Actress (for anyone keeping score, the data do not include her most recent nomination). When the inner join was performed between the `ba` and the Dates of Birth, `DOB`, dataframes, every movie for which she was nominated was repeated 16 times, which was not the result I wanted (see erroneous results above). As it so happens, her name and date of birth appeared 16 times in the `DOB` dataframe. This is consistent with the scrape code I wrote and not at all an unexpected result or bug.

When I did the inner join between the two frames, I (wrongly) thought Pandas would see her nomination for, say, "Julie & Julia," match her birthday once, and be done with it. Apparently, the inner join means that if there is a match on the join column in both tables, every row will be matched the maximum number of times possible. Hence, for every single film, the combined table had 16 records (one for her 16 best actress nominations, which equalled the number of times her birthday appeared in a web scrape of nominee birthdays that became a dataframe). I'm not sure if this is correct, but it describes what I saw it front of me. I welcome clarification on this one.

The workaround was simply to remove duplicate names from the `DOB` dataframe and remerge. Here's the code and output, using Meryl as our example.

```
ba_dob_revised = df_birthdays.drop_duplicates('Name')
ba_dob = pd.merge(ba, ba_dob_revised, on='Name')
ba_dob[ba_dob.Name=="Meryl Streep"] 

{'Award': {282: 'Best Actress',
  283: 'Best Actress',
  284: 'Best Actress',
  285: 'Best Actress',
  286: 'Best Actress',
  287: 'Best Actress',
  288: 'Best Actress',
  289: 'Best Actress',
  290: 'Best Actress',
  291: 'Best Actress',
  292: 'Best Actress',
  293: 'Best Actress',
  294: 'Best Actress',
  295: 'Best Actress',
  296: 'Best Actress'},
 'Ceremony': {282: 54,
  283: 55,
  284: 56,
  285: 58,
  286: 60,
  287: 61,
  288: 63,
  289: 68,
  290: 71,
  291: 72,
  292: 79,
  293: 81,
  294: 82,
  295: 84,
  296: 86},
 'Ceremony_Date': {282: Timestamp('1982-03-29 00:00:00'),
  283: Timestamp('1983-04-11 00:00:00'),
  284: Timestamp('1984-04-09 00:00:00'),
  285: Timestamp('1986-03-24 00:00:00'),
  286: Timestamp('1988-04-11 00:00:00'),
  287: Timestamp('1989-03-29 00:00:00'),
  288: Timestamp('1991-03-25 00:00:00'),
  289: Timestamp('1996-03-25 00:00:00'),
  290: Timestamp('1999-03-21 00:00:00'),
  291: Timestamp('2000-03-26 00:00:00'),
  292: Timestamp('2007-02-25 00:00:00'),
  293: Timestamp('2009-02-22 00:00:00'),
  294: Timestamp('2010-03-07 00:00:00'),
  295: Timestamp('2012-02-26 00:00:00'),
  296: Timestamp('2014-03-02 00:00:00')},
 'DOB': {282: Timestamp('1949-06-22 00:00:00'),
  283: Timestamp('1949-06-22 00:00:00'),
  284: Timestamp('1949-06-22 00:00:00'),
  285: Timestamp('1949-06-22 00:00:00'),
  286: Timestamp('1949-06-22 00:00:00'),
  287: Timestamp('1949-06-22 00:00:00'),
  288: Timestamp('1949-06-22 00:00:00'),
  289: Timestamp('1949-06-22 00:00:00'),
  290: Timestamp('1949-06-22 00:00:00'),
  291: Timestamp('1949-06-22 00:00:00'),
  292: Timestamp('1949-06-22 00:00:00'),
  293: Timestamp('1949-06-22 00:00:00'),
  294: Timestamp('1949-06-22 00:00:00'),
  295: Timestamp('1949-06-22 00:00:00'),
  296: Timestamp('1949-06-22 00:00:00')},
 'Film': {282: "The French Lieutenant's Woman",
  283: "Sophie's Choice",
  284: 'Silkwood',
  285: 'Out of Africa',
  286: 'Ironweed',
  287: 'A Cry in the Dark',
  288: 'Postcards from the Edge',
  289: 'The Bridges of Madison County',
  290: 'One True Thing',
  291: 'Music of the Heart',
  292: 'The Devil Wears Prada',
  293: 'Doubt',
  294: 'Julie & Julia',
  295: 'The Iron Lady',
  296: 'August: Osage County'},
 'Name': {282: 'Meryl Streep',
  283: 'Meryl Streep',
  284: 'Meryl Streep',
  285: 'Meryl Streep',
  286: 'Meryl Streep',
  287: 'Meryl Streep',
  288: 'Meryl Streep',
  289: 'Meryl Streep',
  290: 'Meryl Streep',
  291: 'Meryl Streep',
  292: 'Meryl Streep',
  293: 'Meryl Streep',
  294: 'Meryl Streep',
  295: 'Meryl Streep',
  296: 'Meryl Streep'},
 'Winner': {282: nan,
  283: 1.0,
  284: nan,
  285: nan,
  286: nan,
  287: nan,
  288: nan,
  289: nan,
  290: nan,
  291: nan,
  292: nan,
  293: nan,
  294: nan,
  295: 1.0,
  296: nan},
 'Year': {282: '1981',
  283: '1982',
  284: '1983',
  285: '1985',
  286: '1987',
  287: '1988',
  288: '1990',
  289: '1995',
  290: '1998',
  291: '1999',
  292: '2006',
  293: '2008',
  294: '2009',
  295: '2011',
  296: '2013'}}
```

**Key Takeaway:** While an inner join was appropriate (switching join types certainly did not fix the problem), I did not fully consider how the machine/Pandas thought about an inner join. Ultimately, identifying a pattern in the erroneous result and finding a similar pattern in one of the dataframes, both of which had already been inspected for errors, proved most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

When I run I get no duplicates:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on='Name')
```

printing with:

```
print(json.dumps(json.loads(df.to_json()),indent=4))
```

I get:

```
{
    "Winner": {
        "0": null,
        "1": 1.0,
        "3": null,
        "2": null
    },
    "Ceremony": {
        "0": 1,
        "1": 1,
        "3": 2,
        "2": 1
    },
    "Year": {
        "0": "1927/1928",
        "1": "1927/1928",
        "3": "1928/1929",
        "2": "1927/1928"
    },
    "Film": {
        "0": "A Ship Comes In",
        "1": "7th Heaven",
        "3": "Madame X",
        "2": "Sadie Thompson"
    },
    "Name": {
        "0": "Louise Dresser",
        "1": "Janet Gaynor",
        "3": "Ruth Chatterton",
        "2": "Gloria Swanson"
    },
    "Award": {
        "0": "Best Actress",
        "1": "Best Actress",
        "3": "Best Actress",
        "2": "Best Actress"
    },
    "DOB": {
        "0": -2878243200000,
        "1": -1995667200000,
        "3": -2430518400000,
        "2": -2233180800000
    },
    "Ceremony_Date": {
        "0": -1282176000000,
        "1": -1282176000000,
        "3": -1254355200000,
        "2": -1282176000000
    }
}
```

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">  <thead>    <tr style="text-align: right;">      <th></th>      <th>Award</th>      <th>Ceremony</th>      <th>Ceremony_Date</th>      <th>Film</th>      <th>Name</th>      <th>Winner</th>      <th>Year</th>      <th>DOB</th>    </tr>  </thead>  <tbody>    <tr>      <th>0</th>      <td>Best Actress</td>      <td>1</td>      <td>1929-05-16</td>      <td>A Ship Comes In</td>      <td>Louise Dresser</td>      <td>NaN</td>      <td>1927/1928</td>      <td>1878-10-17</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>1</th>      <td>Best Actress</td>      <td>1</td>      <td>1929-05-16</td>      <td>7th Heaven</td>      <td>Janet Gaynor</td>      <td>1.0</td>      <td>1927/1928</td>      <td>1906-10-06</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>2</th>      <td>Best Actress</td>      <td>1</td>      <td>1929-05-16</td>      <td>Sadie Thompson</td>      <td>Gloria Swanson</td>      <td>NaN</td>      <td>1927/1928</td>      <td>1899-03-27</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>3</th>      <td>Best Actress</td>      <td>2</td>      <td>1930-04-03</td>      <td>Madame X</td>      <td>Ruth Chatterton</td>      <td>NaN</td>      <td>1928/1929</td>      <td>1892-12-24</td>    </tr>  </tbody></table>
```

And

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on='Name')
```

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">  <thead>    <tr style="text-align: right;">      <th></th>      <th>Award</th>      <th>Ceremony</th>      <th>Ceremony_Date</th>      <th>Film</th>      <th>Name</th>      <th>Winner</th>      <th>Year</th>      <th>DOB</th>    </tr>  </thead>  <tbody>    <tr>      <th>0</th>      <td>Best Actress</td>      <td>1.0</td>      <td>1929-05-16</td>      <td>A Ship Comes In</td>      <td>Louise Dresser</td>      <td>NaN</td>      <td>1927/1928</td>      <td>1878-10-17</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>1</th>      <td>Best Actress</td>      <td>1.0</td>      <td>1929-05-16</td>      <td>7th Heaven</td>      <td>Janet Gaynor</td>      <td>1.0</td>      <td>1927/1928</td>      <td>1906-10-06</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>2</th>      <td>Best Actress</td>      <td>1.0</td>      <td>1929-05-16</td>      <td>Sadie Thompson</td>      <td>Gloria Swanson</td>      <td>NaN</td>      <td>1927/1928</td>      <td>1899-03-27</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>3</th>      <td>Best Actress</td>      <td>2.0</td>      <td>1930-04-03</td>      <td>Madame X</td>      <td>Ruth Chatterton</td>      <td>NaN</td>      <td>1928/1929</td>      <td>1892-12-24</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>4</th>      <td>Best Actress</td>      <td>2.0</td>      <td>1930-04-03</td>      <td>The Barker</td>      <td>Betty Compson</td>      <td>NaN</td>      <td>1928/1929</td>      <td>NaT</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>5</th>      <td>NaN</td>      <td>NaN</td>      <td>NaT</td>      <td>NaN</td>      <td>Mary Pickford</td>      <td>NaN</td>      <td>NaN</td>      <td>1892-04-08</td>    </tr>  </tbody></table>
```

Comment: I get the same results: no duplicates in merged df. Using Pandas 0.20.2, Python 3.6.1 @Ryan: are you sure your `ba` df isn't screwy? Does it have a bunch of extra rows that you're seeing in the merged df?

Comment: The `ba` dataframe looks good. The actresses' names should repeat, but the films should, and do, not. I'll add another Meryl Streep excerpt in dictionary form.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) method. For example:

```py
merged_df = pd.merge(left_df, right_df, on='common_key', how='inner').drop_duplicates()
```